# ldapjs, how to delete attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldapjs

I want to use [Node.js ldapjs client api #modify](http://ldapjs.org/client.html#modify) to delete an attribute of an LDAP entry.

Via shell and `ldapmodify ... -f removeAttribute.ldif` it works, using the following ldif file:

```
dn: uid=user,dc=test
changetype: modify
delete: myAttribute
```

Following the ldapjs documentation I have to use operation `'delete'` and to add the attribute to modification (...*Deletes the attribute (and all values) referenced in modification*...).

If I try to do that using ldapjs, I get errors.

```
let dn = 'uid=user,dc=test';
let change = { operation : 'delete', modification: { myAttribute: null } ;
client.modify(dn, change, err => { ... });
```

... leads to error *Cannot read property 'toString' of null*

```
let dn = 'uid=user,dc=test';
let change = { operation : 'delete', modification: { myAttribute: oldValue } };
client.modify(dn, change, err => { ... });
```

... leads to *InappropriateMatchingError*

So my question: how I have to prepare the *change* object, if I want to delete an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that the reason is a bug inside [ldapjs/change.js](https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/blob/master/lib/change.js#L86). If a value is given for a delete operation on a non multi-valued attribute, the LDAP-server will deny execution. If you set the value to `null` or `undefined` in the change object, ldapjs will throw an error, because the *toString()* method cannot be used on *null* or *undefined*.

I have fixed that piece of code, and now it works. See the [ldapjs GitHub pull request 435](https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/pull/435).

The modification value can now be set to `undefined` or `null`. That leads to a request without any attribute value. This request is accepted and executed by the LDAP server, the attribute is deleted.

```
let change = { operation : 'delete', modification: { attributeName : undefined }};
client.modify(dn, change, (err, res) => { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing an empty array seems to work. Until the bug is fixed, that is my workaround.

```
let change = { operation : 'delete', modification: { myAttribute: [] } };
```